# Where is the flaw in my equal stacks algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm

This is the problem where you have stacks of cylinders and you remove top cylinders until the stacks are equal height.

Sample input:

```
5 3 4
3 2 1 1 1
4 3 2
1 1 4 1
```

The stacks have 5, 3, and 4 cylinders and the respective heights of those cylinders are given on the next lines.

Expected output:

```
5
```

My program's output:

```
7
```

My program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        Func<string,int[]> GetIntsFromLine = (line) => Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        int numcyls = GetIntsFromLine(Console.ReadLine()).Length;
        int[][] cyls = new int[numcyls][]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < numcyls; ++i)
            cyls[i] = GetIntsFromLine(Console.ReadLine());
        // now the j-th cylinder stacked on the i-th stach has height cyls[i][j]

        while(true)
        {
              var heights = from cyl in cyls
                            select cyl.Sum();
              int h1 = heights.First();
              if(heights.All(h => h == h1)) // if equal heights
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(h1);
                  return; 
              }
              // if here, "remove" the top cylinder from the stack with the largest height
              int[] st = cyls[heights.ToList().IndexOf(heights.Max())];
              int j = Array.IndexOf(st, 0);
              st[j == -1 ? (st.Length - 1) : j] = 0;            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @David I know how to debug. That doesn't solve the problem of their being a flaw in the algorithm.

Comment: Then where specifically does the problem become evident?  When *you* debug this, where does the logic differ from what you would expect?  So far this is a classic "here's all my code, debug it for me" question.

Comment: Explain how you reach the result "5". Personnally I find "7": `3 2 1 1`, `4 3`, `1 1 4 1`

Comment: @KooKiz That's the answer shown on here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal-stacks?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=ze

Comment: @user6048670 You're taking the input in the wrong order. `3`, in the first stack, is the top cylinder, not the bottom one. See the schema on HackerRank

Comment: @user6048670 The first number is the top of the stack. You're removing from the wrong end

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's solve the problem. So we have three stacks:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
1, 4, 1, 1
```

By taking 0, 1, 2, 3 ... (that's equal to removing 5, 4, 3, 2...) items
from the first stack we can have

```
0                 == 0
1                 == 1
1 + 1             == 2
1 + 1 + 1         == 3
1 + 1 + 1 + 2     == 5 <- this is the solution
1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 == 8
```

substacks. So we can produce

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 (from the 1st)
0, 2, 5, 9       (from the 2nd)
0, 1, 5, 6, 7    (from the 3d)
```

and we should take the maximum value that's pesented in all lines (possible substacks) - 5. Implementation:

```
String input =
  "5 3 4\n" +
  "3 2 1 1 1\n" +
  "4 3 2\n" +
  "1 1 4 1";

var raw = input.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Skip(1) // We don't need 1st control line
  .Select(line => line
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Reverse() // <- do not forget this!
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x))); 

// All possible substacks per each stack
List<HashSet<int>> data = new List<HashSet<int>>();

foreach (var record in raw) {
  HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>() { 0 };

  data.Add(hs);

  int agg = 0;

  foreach (var item in record)
    hs.Add(agg += item);
}

// Values that are in all substacks:
HashSet<int> intersect = new HashSet<int>(data[0]);

foreach (var line in data)
  intersect.IntersectWith(line); 

// And, finally, the maximum one:
Console.Write(intersect.Max());
```